# jQuery image sliding plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins, slider

I have multiple images for a image set. Say an image set have 10 images, all are of different size and of different types like .jpg, .png etc.

I want a jQuery based plugin which will have next, previous and caption title functionality, and on next and previous it will slide my images accordingly.

I am managing the size (width & height) of images (via PHP code), say an image is larger than 700px then I am automatically resizing it by adding `style="width:700px; height:auto;"` in the `img` tag of image. Which managing the image size automatically according to the page.

All images size is variying, some are of 400 KB and some are of 2 MB but not more than 2 MB.

I used galleria plugin to achieve this, and it has almost all the functionality, but the problem is due to large image size browse takes time to load images but galleria JS runs and gives error in the meantime. I also used nivoSlider, but that doesn't have sliding effect, so if 1st image is larger then 2nd image displayed on top of it.

Comment: Have you looked into the jQuery Cycle plugin? This gives you access to the triggers so you could wait for image load before starting the transition.

Answer (score 3):

Try out jquery ui library which has slider for images

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be **NivoSlider** and **anythingSlider** - they look more fancy. Just google for their names

Comment: I tried Nivo, its doesn't have any sliding effect, only fade and some other which fails (displayed one image over other) in case of large images. Will check about anythingslider.